# Change in value based on criteria with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to compute sth like a running difference with linq on a list but cant get it to work.

Here is what I m trying to do (**simplification version**):

```
 public class SampleCl
{
    public string label;
    public double val;
    public double valdiff;
}
```

I have a class with values and a label and a third double with is supposed to hold the differences.

Some sample data:

```
        var samplelist = new List<SampleCl>();
        samplelist.Add(new SampleCl {label ="A", val= 1 });
        samplelist.Add(new SampleCl { label = "B", val = 2 });
        samplelist.Add(new SampleCl { label = "C", val = 3 });
```

The code below doesnt work but shows nicely what I want to do:

```
        samplelist.Where(a => a.valdiff = a.val - a.val.Where(a.label=="B"));
```

valdiff should than hold -1, 0, 1 for A, B , C respectively

Comment: Linq is not meant for mutating.  You're better off doing this in a `foreach`.

Comment: I´m not sure if I understand what you mean. Do you want to select all difference-values from your sample-list to the element with `label=B

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I would like to use the value with label "B" a substractor and deduct this from all values and store the result in valdiff.

Comment: @juharr: fair enough, thought there was an easy way that I just dont know about. Obviously in a foreach it is relatively straigth forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do this in one line then you need to use the [`ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
But in my opinion this is in no way better than a simple foreach loop and is more weak in terms of control on the presence of the base value used to calculate the difference

```
samplelist.ForEach(x => x.valdiff = 
                        (x.val - samplelist.FirstOrDefault
                                 (s => s.label== "B").val));
```

Instead a simple foreach loop would be a lot simpler, more understandable and will allow you to introduce a fine check on the presence of the item with the key value.

```
// Assuming that you want to use zero if the item with label == B doesn't exist
double num = 0;
SampleCl baseItem = samplelist.FirstOrDefault(s => x.label == "B");
if(baseItem != null) num = baseItem.val;
foreach(var item in samplelist)
    item.valdiff = item.val - num;
```

Comment: Technically `ForEach` isn't Linq.  It's just a method of `List<T>`.

Comment: `ForEach` is not an extension method.  It's a concrete method on `List<T>`.

Comment: @juharr again you are correct, this tells you a lot how often I use this method.

Comment: thanks. very embarrassing, i just realized that was to simple to solve my actual problem. Should i amend the question or ask a new one?

Comment: No it is a legitimate question. If you have a new problem then do not hesitate to ask a new question

Comment: @nik Note that this specific `ForEach` example has a exponential complexity because the `FirstOrDefault` search is done for each item in the list.  If you have a large list it would be better to save that in a variable that you use in the `ForEach` to get a linear complexity.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to do something like this.

```
var b = samplelist.First(a => a.label=="B");
foreach(var samp in samplelist)
    samp.valdiff = samp.val - b.val;
```

Answer (score 2):

There you go with the help of foreach.

```
samplelist.ForEach(s => s.valdiff = s.val - samplelist.Single(b => b.label == "B").val);
```

Comment: thank you. what is the difference between single vs first/firstordefault pls?

Comment: Single will throw an exception if no element satisfying the condition is found.

Comment: and firstordefault will use a zero as default value given val is a double?

Comment: @nik `First` will throw if there isn't at least one match.  `Single` will also throw if there is more than one match.  The "OrDefault" versions simply return the default value when there is no match, but `SingleOrDefault` will still throw if there is more than one match.

Comment: Which one of those functions you should chose will then depend on your use case @nik. You should ask yourself: should there be classes with the same label in place? Should always be at least one "B" labeled class in the collection?

Comment: thanks. very embarrassing, i just realized that was to simple to solve my actual problem. Should i amend the question or ask a new one?

Comment: If it's still in the same context of the actual question just edit it. Otherwise I'd rather start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this may work:

```
var val = sampleList.Single(x => x.label == "B").val;
sampleList = sampleList.Select(x => new SampleCl 
    {
        label = x.label,
        val = x.val,
        valdiff = x.value - val
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Although this is a valid example I'd rather discourage from using it. It is basically the same as all other solutions here but with the extra step of recreating the list again. In this simple solution it won't matter but if you're operating on a much larger dataset this will make a huge difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LINQ only there is this only possibility to do that:

```
var result = from a in samplelist
                let b = samplelist.FirstOrDefault(b => b.label == "B")
                let ab = a.valdiff = a.val - b.val
                select a;
```

Comment: Mutating in a Linq query is pure evil.

Comment: It is nothing else than samplelist.ForEach(....) does! I just answered the question according to requirements!

Comment: Note that this code doesn't actually mutate the original list until you iterate `result`.